# How to use editor font in search dialog?

Tags: intellij-idea, rider

How can I setup JetBrains IDEA/Rider to use the editor font in the search/find dialog?

Answer (score 0):

`Help` -> `Edit Custom Properties...`

add the following line

```
ide.find.use.editor.font=true
```

[image]